# do i need to add any code to PHP after using SSL

Tags: php, ssl, https

i'm using a simple contact form on my website using PHP, and i'm about to install SSL on my website, codewise do i need to make any changes to the PHP code, i'm totaly new to SSL and this is my first SSL installation .

```
<?php
$errors = array();
$missing = array();
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
$to = 'john@example.com';
$subject = 'Feedback from contact form';
$expected = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
$required = array('name', 'email', 'comments');
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";
require './includes/mail_process.php';
    if ($mailSent) {
    header('Location: thanks.php');
    exit;
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
<link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<?php if ($_POST && $suspect) { ?>
<p class="warning">Sorry your mail could not be be sent.</p>
<?php } elseif ($errors || $missing) { ?>
<p class="warning">Please fix the item(s) indicated.</p>
<?php }?>
<form name="contact" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p>
    <label for="name">Name:
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('name', $missing)) { ?>
    <span class="warning">Please enter your name</span>
    <?php } ?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
    <?php
    if ($errors || $missing) {
        echo 'value="' . htmlentities($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8') . '"';
    }
    ?>
    >
</p>
<p>
    <label for="email">Email:
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('email', $missing)) { ?>
    <span class="warning">Please enter your email address</span>
    <?php } elseif (isset($errors['email'])) { ?>
    <span class="warning">Invalid email address</span>
    <?php } ?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"
    <?php
    if ($errors || $missing) {
        echo 'value="' . htmlentities($email, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8') . '"';
    }
    ?>
    >
</p>
<p>
    <label for="comments">Comments:
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('comments', $missing)) { ?>
    <span class="warning">You forgot to add your comments</span>
    <?php } ?>
    </label>
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments"><?php 
    if ($errors || $missing) {
        echo htmlentities($comments, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
    }
    ?></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send Comments">
</p>
</form>
<pre>
</body>
</html>
```

the mail_process.php goes like this

```
<?php
$suspect = false;
$pattern = '/Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';

function isSuspect($val, $pattern, &$suspect) {
if (is_array($val)) {
    foreach ($val as $item) {
        isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
    }
} else {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
        $suspect = true;
    }
}
}

isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);

if (!$suspect) {
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
    if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
        $missing[] = $key;
        $$key = '';
    } elseif(in_array($key, $expected)) {
        $$key = $temp;
    }
}
}

if (!$suspect && !empty($email)) {
$validemail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($validemail) {
    $headers .= "\r\nReply-to: $validemail";
} else {
    $errors['email'] = true;
}
}

if (!$suspect && !$missing && !$errors) {
$message = '';
foreach ($expected as $item) {
    if (isset($$item) && !empty($$item)) {
        $val = $$item;
    } else {
        $val = 'Not selected';
    }
    if (is_array($val)) {
        $val = implode(', ', $val);
    }
    $item = str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $item);
    $message .= ucfirst($item) . ": $val\r\n\r\n";
}
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

$mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $authenticate); 
if (!$mailSent) {
    $errors['mailfail'] = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have any absolute URL references you won't have a problem. I'd recommend you put this in your header (or at the top of all your PHP files) to force them to use https, that way if you did need absolute URLs in your website, you can have them all HTTPS as everyone would be forced there anyway.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on' || !stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.')) {
    $redirect= "https://www.".str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location:$redirect");
}
```

Comment: what if i used absolute URLs on the page

Comment: You could always force https then if you needed to have absolute URLs you could make them HTTPS and not worry about it.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change absolute URL's to "https://....". If you are not using absolute URL's there is nothing to change if your form and processing script are both on https.